# How to parse a complex csv into multiple dataframes with Python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have relatively complex csv files which contain multiple matrices representing several types of data and I would like to be able to parse these into multiple dataframes.

The complication is that these files are quite variable in size and content, as seen in [this example containing two types of data, in this case a Median and Count metric for each sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRJYC.jpg).

There are some commonalities that all of these files share. Each metric will be stored in a matrix structured essentially like the two in the above example. In particular, the DataType field and subsequent entry will always be there, and the feature space (columns) and sample space (rows) will be consistent *within* a file (the row space may vary *between* files).

Essentially, the end result should be a dataframe of the data for just one metric, with the feature ids as the column names (Analyte 1, Analyte 2, etc in this example) and the sample ids as the row names (Location column in this case).

So far I've attempted this using the pandas read_csv function without much success.

In theory I could do something like this, but only if I know (1) the size and (2) the location of the particular matrix for the metric that I am after. In this case the headers for my particular metric of interest would be in row 46 and I happen to know that the number of samples is 384.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', sep = ",", header=46, nrows=385, index_col='Location')
```

I am at a complete loss how to do this in a dynamic fashion with files and matrices that change dimensions. Any input on overall strategy here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't say for the rest of the question, but the example data you gave can't/shouldn't be read as a single CSV file. If you can isolate both the tables which begin after the `DataType` rows, those should be fine.

Comment: The general strategy is to first read the input file as text, and accumulate each relevant part in a large string if it can fit in memory or in a temp file. As soon as a part is ready, you can then load it into a dataframe with `read_csv(fd, ...)` for a file or `read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), ...)` for a string.