# Why can't pandas read this text file for data? 'invalid start byte

Tags: python-3.x

Heyo smart peeps, I am trying to use pandas to read this text file, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 2988: invalid start byte
```

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd

#df = pd.read_csv("PS.prg1903-001_KSK_LB__0_00001.txt")
 
#df = pd.read_csv("PS.prg1903-001_KSK_LB__0_00001.txt", encoding="ISO-8859-1")

df = pd.read_csv("PS.prg1903-001_KSK_LB__0_00001.txt", encoding="latin1")
 
print(df)
```

I really don't want to use a simple read function, as I have no idea how to convert a list of numbers as strings into a table. Also, the three df functions are all different things I have tried, but all gave the same error. I will also attach a sample of what the data looks like. Thank you to anyone who gives this a read!

[Link to sample data!](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4qlbah6yrw99fx/sample.txt?dl=0)

Comment: The data don't start until several rows down in the file. You might try telling read_csv which rows are the header rows, by adding `header=(10,11)`. The numbers are just examples I didn't count them, but it looks like you have two header rows so they'll have to be specified as I've shown. Also you a

Comment: That seems to work, but now I am getting the error: TypeError: an integer is required.

Comment: I tried looking for the solution, but there really isnt much online

Comment: You might try cutting the data file down to something simpler then building up from there.  You might try adding sep='\s+' to say the fields are separated by multiple spaces, not commas. Also note that the header specification probably starts at 0, not 1.

Comment: this question is similar:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60158368/how-to-parse-a-complex-csv-into-multiple-dataframes-with-python-and-pandas